# Firefox Proxy - How to avoid the websites seeing my real ip?

Tags: firefox, proxy

Im trying to use a proxy with firefox, but the issue is that some sites are getting my real ip.

-If I enter to http://www.showmemyip.com it shows me the proxy ip.

-If I enter to http://www.whatismyip.com it shows me the proxy ip + "No proxy detected"

-If I enter to http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check it shows me the proxy ip + "Proxy server not detected." + everything on false (green)

How can it be possible that they are detecting my ip? I saw that flash doesnt use the proxy configured on firefox... but the pages that Im trying to access dont have any flash script.

Is there any way of being 100% that they would only see the proxy ip and not mine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That because the proxy pass your ip to server in http header([detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Accessing_services_anonymously)), you should setup the proxy to anonymously.

Comment: Thanks for your response... Unfortunately we already checked that, we entered to several websites that shows all the headers and there is no header that shows our real ip. We were aware that some proxies do that, but this is not the case. Indeed we use proxies from a page that sells proxies for "anonymous" purposes, it would go against their business to send the user real ip as a header. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There are some Java and Flash hacks to find out the visitor's real IP even behind a proxy server. As for Java you can turn it off forever. For Flash install some browser extension to be able to block it when you need. Use this site for tests: http://mylocation.org